# C# remove item from queue

Tags: c#, queue

I have code from this side

http://www.algorytm.org/klasyczne/kolejka/kolejka-1-cs.html

I create queue:
2(first),3,4,2,4,3,4,2(last)

**What I need to do:**

Create a method that remove an item "2" from this queue.

Thx.

Comment: FWIW .NET has a built-in `Queue` collection type.

Comment: Please show us what you have done.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/MCHYFRat my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your collected code is so annoying (it's Polish writing, not English).

I just can help you by providing pseudocode:

```
DelItem(Item, PrevE, CurrE)
  1. If CurrE= LastE
        If CurrE.Item = Item
            PrevE.Next = null
            Delete(CurrE)
        return
  2. NextE = CurrE.Next
  3. If CurrE.Item = Item
        PrevE.Next = NextE
        Delete(CurrE)
        CurrE = PrevE
        NextE = CurrE.Next
  4. DelItem(Item, CurrE, NextE)
```

Comment: Is there less annoying now?  https://pastebin.com/MCHYFRat